# Will an external GPU work on a MacBook Pro if I boot Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon

I want to start mining cryptocurrencies and I already have a spare 2016 MacBook Pro model but I realized that I would need a GPU to mine some currencies.

Will installing Ubuntu on my Mac make it compatible with GPUs like AMD Radeon R9 290X and NVIDIA TITAN X, etc.?

Will it be tough to set up the GPU?

Comment: You do understand it's extremely inefficient to mine most crytograhic currencies (at least any of them with any significant real world value) in most cases it will cost you to turn the machine on then what you will actually earn.

Comment: How were you planning to connect these GPUs to the MacBook?

Comment: @music2myear No idea! I was hoping to find out if there were any ways of doing so as I read it at [here](https://9to5mac.com/2017/04/11/hands-on-powering-the-macbook-pro-with-an-egpu-using-nvidias-new-pascal-drivers/)

Comment: @Ramhound I live on university campus and I don't think there will be any setup or running costs for me except getting the first GPU ~200/300 dollars I guess.

Comment: @Ramhound I could maybe setup 2 or 3 good gpus and leave them on 24 hours

Comment: Given that you've already referenced a site with a how-to on this, what is your question? If the GPUs will work with Ubuntu?

Comment: @MananMehta You really should do more research.  It's very unlikely you will ever generate enough to ever make your investment back.  If you go into this endeavor knowing that fact, I can rest easy, you are better off just buying the currencies and waiting for their value to increase

Comment: @music2myear Yes. Will an external GPU work with Ubuntu on a macbook?

Comment: @Ramhound You're right. I will do a little more research before going into this. I thought mining ether would be profitable but there are great uncertainties with the hard fork coming soon